# response code 250 laravel email authentication required

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel[5.2] beautymail package but I encountered this error

> Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1
>   Authentication required "

, I already reverted my .env file to its original. Do i have to configure something in order to send an email. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First make it sure that you have entered your email, password. tls, port in `.env` file. Eg: --

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=some@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Then dont forget to close `php artisan serve` and use it again.

It is because every time you change the `.env` file you need to re-run the session